# How to share Text and URL to Reminders on iOS 13

Tags: swift, ios13, uiactivityviewcontroller, reminders

I use Sharesheet to share Text and URL to Reminders, iMessages, Mail, Notes.

On iMessages, Mail and Notes, Text and URL are displayed normally.

[image]

But on Reminders, nothing is displayed.

[image]

Here is my source code:

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [self], applicationActivities: nil)
```

=======

```
extension ShareActivityItemSource: UIActivityItemSource {

    public func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> Any {
        return self.title
    }

    public func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: UIActivityType?) -> Any? {
        return "\(self.title)\t\n\(self.url)"
    }

    func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, subjectForActivityType activityType: UIActivityType?) -> String {
        return self.title
    }

    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    func activityViewControllerLinkMetadata(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> LPLinkMetadata? {
        let metadata = LPLinkMetadata()
        metadata.title = self.title
        metadata.url = self.url
        metadata.iconProvider = NSItemProvider(contentsOf: self.thumbnailUrl)
        return metadata
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: I noticed that this is only happening in simulator. In device it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this.

At first, you have to create event store:

`self.eventStore = EKEventStore()`

Than you need to create the reminder:

```
    private func makeReminder(pass your params here) -> EKReminder {
        let reminder = EKReminder(eventStore: self.eventStore)
        reminder.title = title
        reminder.notes = notes
        reminder.url = url 
        return reminder
}
```

And after that you need to save it:

```
try self.eventStore.save(reminder, commit: true)
```

Hope I've answered on your question.